# Stop a YouTube video from buffering

Tags: youtube

If I land on a page embedded with more than one YouTube video, I may not watch them in order or all the way through but they will continue buffering even if I no longer want to watch them.

Say I start the first video and after few seconds I don't want to watch the rest of it. If I want the second video to play instead I will pause the first. But the first video will still buffer as I'm trying to view the second.

How do I stop buffering a YouTube video?

What I usually do is just refresh the page before going to the next video.

Is there any other way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Right-click on the video and select **Stop downloading**. To start it up again click the pause/play button.

Another way is to move the slider all the way to the end or near end of the video timeline. That way only the few remaining seconds left to play will end up streaming down to your computer and when it finishes, that's it. No more buffering or loading.